# How to get one output for avg function?

Tags: mysql

I have a table world_temps and a column for year, country_Code, avg_mon_temp

I am trying to find the average monthly temperature per country (GBR, IRL, USA, AUS) for the years 1901 - 2015, below is the method I am using now

SELECT country_Code, year, avg_mon_temp FROM world_temps WHERE year BETWEEN 1901 AND 2015 GROUP BY country_Code, year;

However this displays an average temp for each  year from 1901 to 2015, how do I get the one average for each country for all these years together, not individual outputs for each year?

Comment: Sample data would greatly help your question.

Comment: remove year from group by